# help with this java program

Tags: java

Im writing a java program to input year and month in the format "1999-5" meaning year 1999 and month june. (months start from 0=jan,1=feb).

Where 1999 is the year and 5 is the numeric sequence of the month (corresponding to June). The program should display the day on which June 28, 1999 fell, and in this case the output will be MONDAY.

I have the logic and partial code. I input a string, split it, parse it to integer and to the processing. How do I separate the "-" delimiter in the string input.

The program's input should be "1999-5"
output should be MONDAY. (june 28, 1999 falls on monday)

```
int num;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String name=sc.nextLine();
String delimiter = "-";

temp= name.split(delimiter);

num= Integer.parseInt(name);

System.out.println(temp);
System.out.println(num);
```

Kindly tell me if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Why are you printing temp? The split method returns a String array so you should parseInt on temp[0] and temp[1] (if they exist of course).

Comment: no no im not printing temp. I was testing the code so I messed it up a little.

Answer (score 2):

Update with the idea from @TheStijn using pattern with `"-dd"` to manipulate the input.

But we also need to manipulate the Month to get June for input `5`

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = sc.nextLine();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
formatter.setLenient(false);
int year = Integer.parseInt(name.substring( 0, name.lastIndexOf( '-' ) ));
int month = Integer.parseInt(name.substring( name.lastIndexOf( '-' )+1 ));
Date date = formatter.parse(year+"-"+(month+1)+"-28");

if( date != null ) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Comment: I don't think month + 1 is required; look at the first line in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you're better off using `SimpeDateFormat`.

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(name + "-28")
```

Use `Calendar` to get day of the week:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(d);
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
//switch (dayOfWeek) ...
```

Comment: Does `SimpleDateFormat` care that there is no leading 0 on the month when you specify `MM` or do you need to use just `M` instead?

Comment: No it doesn't care, 2011-5 will work fine with format yyyy-MM

Comment: @veredesmarald: like thestijn said, it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    String name = "1999-5";
    String[] temp = name.split("-");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
```

Beware that `parseInt()` may throw a `NumberFormatException`, so you may want to catch it.

BTW, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) can get the day of the week for you: have a look [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Querying_DateTimes).

Comment: @TheStijin: I didn't notice that the question was tagged as `homework`

Comment: @macro: I didn't tag it as a homework! I don't know how that came.

Comment: @user750092: another SO user with higher reputation has tagged as such, because your question looked like `homework`. Is it really `homework`? If not, I can remove the tag.

Comment: It's not homework though it looks like one. It is a problem my friend was stuck on. He is clear now. Thanks to u guys on SO.. Doesn't matter if it's tagged as homework too.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` should be a string array (`String[] temp`), and you parseInt,  num[0] and num[1] to get 1999 and 5 respectively.